# Weighted least squares

Tags: regression, self-study, least-squares, weighted-regression

> Consider the estimator $b_1=\frac{\sum y_i}{\sum x_i}$. Suppose that $y_i = \beta x_i + \epsilon_i$, $E[\epsilon_i]=0$, $E[\epsilon_i \epsilon_j] (i \neq j)$ and $E[\epsilon_i^2]=\sigma_i^2$. Find a model for the variance of $b_1$ for which th estimator is BLUE.

The answer is supposed to be:

> $v_i=x_i$ and $\sigma_i^2=\sigma^2 x_i$

However, I am not sure how they got to this answer. Could anyone please help?

---

*Update:*
I tried computing the variance of $b_1$. I get:
$$
{\rm Var}(b_1)=\frac 1 {(∑x^2_i)^2}∑x^2_i\ {\rm Var}(\varepsilon_i)
$$
I don't see however how I could proceed from here or whether this was the right thing to do.

Comment: Please see [the self-study tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Can you say a little about what you have tried / understand so far?

Comment: @gung I tried computing the variance of $b_1$. I get that $\operatorname{Var}(b_1)=\frac{1}{(\sum x_i^2)^2} \sum x_i^2 \operatorname{Var}(\epsilon_i)$. I don't see however how I could proceed from here or whether this was the right thing to do.

Comment: Should the definition of $b_1$ be different from what you have in the first line (e.g. should it have summation over $i$ or something?)

Comment: @Glen_b Big sorry. That's really sloppy. I edited the OP.

Comment: What's $v_i$ defined to be? It doesn't appear anywhere in the question, but they calculate it in the answer.

Comment: What do you know about BLUE for weighted regression?

Comment: @Glen_b $v_i$ is just a generic expression for the term by which you devide to get the WLS estimator.

Comment: Then it should be easy to define. Is it just a reciprocal of a weight?

Comment: @Glen_b I think WLS is always BLUE if the correct weights are used, right?

Comment: I think so too. But how sure are you? Is it something you would use in a solution to a question like this?

Comment: @glen_b I am pretty sure, so yes. The WLS estimator satisfies all basic assumtpions that the regular OLS estimator satisfies, which is BLUE. So yes I would use it, if I knew how it would help.

Comment: @Glen_b For a definition of $v_i$: $v_i$ is the term in the WLS estimator: $\frac{\sum \frac{1}{v_i} x_i y_i}{\sum \frac{1}{v_i} x_i^2}$.

Comment: Okay, then $v_i$ is simply the reciprocal of the weight, $v_i=1/w_i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For weighted regression through the origin, I presume you either know or can show that $b_1=\frac{\sum_i w_ix_iy_i}{\sum_i w_ix_i^2} = \frac{\sum_i (w_ix_i)y_i}{\sum_i (w_ix_i)x_i}$

Since in this case $b_1=\frac{\sum_i y_i}{\sum x_i}$, you can see by inspection that the weights must be such that $w_ix_i$ is a constant.

Can you do it now?

Comment: Ah, I see it's that easy... I thought variances needed to be computed and compared with that of the OLS estimator. This makes it a lot easier though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I imagine it can be done in several more complicated ways. It's really a matter of what things you are able to take as given, and what things you're required to show. If you can take a few things as given (which it seems you probably can), then it's pretty easy.